# Single login in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0, authentication

I am working on a website for a college project. I want to add a feature to my project website.

When a user logs in to the website, all other logins for the same user account should be logged-out, i.e., only one login per account should be allowed at a time .

When the same user ID is trying to log in on multiple devices, how do I kill the session on the other device?

Comment: Can you please clarify, suppose a userA logged in ,Now if another userB login to the site then UserA will be automatically, logged out ???

Comment: if user A is login from some place X and then he again do login form place Y then login from A should be logged out.

Comment: Please supply more info. What have you tried? What didn't work? This question is not answerable as it is

Comment: Pls see this: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970067/login-security-how-to-disable-multiple-login

Answer (score 0):

You can be out of the situation by doing something like this:

**The Idea**

Whenever a user logs in to their account we store their username along with their Session ID. The next time someone that is logged in tries to make a request, we check if their Session ID matches with the Session ID we stored for them. If it's a mismatch, that means someone else logged in after them! Thus we can safely log them out.

**The Implementation**

We'll make use of 3 things.
Session ID: Allowing us to distinguish someone's browsing instance

Global.asax: To grab the Session End Event

One Storage Location:

HttpContext.Current.Application

Database

If your website is running on one server, then you can just use Application, but if its running on multiple you'll have to go for the Database. The code shows it being done for Application. 
When the user logs in you need to store the session id:

```
UserAccout ua = GetUserAccount();
HttpContext.Current.Application["usr_" + ua.UserName] = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
```

And when they log out we need to clear it:

```
 UserAccout ua = GetUserAccount();
    HttpContext.Current.Application.Remove("usr_" + ua.UserName);
```

In your Global.asax file you should call the same Logout code to clean up when their Session Ends

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
UserAccout ua = GetUserAccount();
if (ua != null)
{
HttpContext.Current.Application.Remove("usr_" + ua.UserName);
}
}
```

And now that we need to actually check if a user should be kicked out or not, so execute this in the beginning of all requests:

```
UserAccout ua = GetUserAccount();
if (!HttpContext.Current.Application["usr_" + ua.UserName].Equals(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID))
{
Logout();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("SignOut.aspx");
}
```